# How to ignore SSL policy when working with a HTTPClient?

Tags: ssl, httpclient

How could I ignore my end SSL certificate using WebClient ? Here is the code I am using at the moment.

I do not see ServicePointManager in my project, why ? I am using HttpCLient to automate some API calls and I want to ignore my SSL. I am using .Net 4.5

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t = new Task(HTTP_GET);
        t.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading page...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    static async void HTTP_GET()
    {

        var TARGETURL = "https://myUrl";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {

        };

        Console.WriteLine("GET: + " + TARGETURL);


        // ... Use HttpClient.            
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:pass");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));


        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(TARGETURL);
        HttpContent content = response.Content;

        // ... Check Status Code                                
        Console.WriteLine("Response StatusCode: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
        // ... Read the string.
        string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // ... Display the result.
        if (result != null && result.Length >= 50)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.Substring(0, 50) + "...");
        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer :) hope that helps.

```
 using System;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Net.Http;


namespace WISetupAPI
{
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t = new Task(HTTP_GET);
        t.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading page...");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }


    static async void HTTP_GET()
    {
        // ... Target page.
        var TARGETURL = "https://Url";

          using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
            using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
            {
                // Make request here.
                Console.WriteLine("GET: + " + TARGETURL);
                var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:pass");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(TARGETURL);
                HttpContent content = response.Content;

                // ... Check Status Code                                
                Console.WriteLine("Response StatusCode: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
                // ... Read the string.
                string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                // ... Display the result.
                if (result != null && result.Length >= 50)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result.Substring(0, 50) + "...");
                }

            }
        }



     }


  }
}
```